# Ansible unicode object has no attribute value json parsing

Tags: json, ansible, openstack

My Task is

```
  - name: task name
    shell: openstack floating ip create provider --format json
    register: result
```

The output will be in below json format

```
   {
  "router_id": null,
  "status": "DOWN",
  "description": "",
  "created_at": "2017-05-24T10:49:15Z",
  "updated_at": "2017-05-24T10:49:15Z",
  "floating_network_id": "923-cc77237b08e7",
  "headers": "",
  "fixed_ip_address": null,
  "floating_ip_address": "192.*.*.*",
  "revision_number": 1,
  "project_id": "2709ad381fcf41c5bce673c916fded10",
  "port_id": null,
  "id": "c5d187elg-d269-4eae-b6ae-7d258f04983"
}
```

What i want to do is,get only the floating_ip_address and store it into a variable so that i can use it in another task.

Im using the below code for doing this,

```
- set_fact:
     address: "{{ (result.stdout | from_json | selectattr('floating_ip_address') | list | first).floating_ip_address }}"
```

But Im getting an error

```
   "ERROR! 'unicode object' has no attribute 'floating_ip_address'"
```

What is correct format to get only the ip address?

Comment: Ya sure..I'll add the command also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `floating_ip_address` is not a list, but a simple key as in your input, for example:

```
- set_fact:
    address: "{{ (result.stdout | from_json)['floating_ip_address'] }}"
```

Comment: I need examples for parsing

Comment: I don't understand what you ask for now.